# Android push notifications not receiving/not sending

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but many also went unanswered.

However, I use Parse.com to send push-notifications to devices. On iOS it works fine. But it's not receives on Android devices.

When I looking at Push tab on service page I see that no one push wasn't sent. Value in 'Pushes Sent' column is 0 (zero).

Then I sent push through GCM (gcm-http.googleapis.com) and my device received the message.

Perhaps the problem may be in settings of Parse.com?

I was added Sender ID (Project number) & API Key from Google.

My AndroidManifest.xml immediately before the opening `</application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<permission android:name="my.app.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.app.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

My AndroidManifest.xml immediately before the closing `</application>` tag:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_bt"/>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="my.app.name" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My ApplicationClass

```java
package my.app.name;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;

public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Parse
        Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully installed.");
                    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to install", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
...
```

On the advice of Clayton Oliveira I noticed, when I install my app and initialize it first time I get my token and pushes works fine. But when I open my app again I get another token and pushes are not working until I delete all data from Parse, uninstall my app & install it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you added ParsePushBroadcastReceiver to your manifest?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko sure, add it to my question

Comment: what you mean by ***API key from Google***?

Comment: @OlegOsipenko it's server key from console.developers.google.com APIs & auth Credentials tab

Comment: why do you need this? maybe the reason in that key? as Parse claims *The Parse Android SDK chooses a reasonable default configuration so that you do not have to worry about GCM registration ids, sender ids, or API keys. In particular, the SDK will automatically register your app for push at startup time using Parse's sender ID (1076345567071) and will store the resulting registration ID in the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation.*

Comment: the only setting you have to make listed here https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

Comment: @OlegOsipenko thanks for your advice, I removed server key, but it's didn't help. I think that pushes not sent to my device, how do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem just now ! Here's what did the trick:

I uninstalled my app and deleted all the data previously stored on Parse (Installation, Session and User).

After that, just install your app again and if you did everything right from the Parse tutorial: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Try send another Test Push ;)

Comment: Hello @user3089649, thanx for your advice. I uninstalled my app and deleted all the data too, but it's didn't help. But what I noticed, when I install my app and do not open it, test pushes are receiving successfully. But if I once open my app pushes are not receiving. I'm confused.

Comment: Can you post you Application Class ?

Comment: Sure, add it to my question post

Comment: I've tried to use your code for reproduce the problem, but no success so far.

Comment: Do you mean your messages are received?

Comment: Thank @ClaytonOliveira, I just re-install my app and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add the permission of the message then add it in to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

and add this firebase lib in app's build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```